# When installing camel-hazelcast in karaf shows error

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

When i tried to install camel-hazelcast 2.15.2 feature in apache karaf 3.0.4 it gives the below error, how to resolve it kindly help to resolve this

> karaf@root()> feature:install camel-hazelcast
>
> Error executing command: Can't install feature camel-hazelcast/0.0.0:
> Manifest not present in the zip mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/1.0.2

Comment: A good idea is to tell us exactly which versions of what you are using, in case anyone want to try to reproduce this, and help you.

Comment: I'm Using apache karaf 3.0.4 and camel-hazelcast 2.15.2

Comment: Any Updates on this issue ?

Comment: Delete karaf and try again. Maybe the downloaded zip is corrupt.

Comment: Steps I followed to install camel-hazelcast           D:\Working\tools\apache-karaf-3.0.4\bin>karaf
karaf@root()> list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
ID | State | Lvl | Version | Name
---------------------------------
karaf@root()> feature:list | grep camel
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add camel 2.15.2
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.15.2/xml/features

Comment: karaf@root()> feature:install  camel-hazelcast
Error executing command: Can't install feature camel-hazelcast/0.0.0:
Manifest not present in the zip mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/1.0.2
karaf@root()> feature:install  camel-core
karaf@root()> list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
ID | State  | Lvl | Version | Name
--------------------------------------------------
81 | Active |  50 | 2.15.2  | camel-core
82 | Active |  50 | 2.15.2  | camel-catalog
83 | Active |  50 | 2.15.2  | camel-commands-core
84 | Active |  50 | 2.15.2  | camel-karaf-commands

Comment: @ClausIbsen Am I following the right way please kindly guide me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a problem on your end. Maybe the downloaded zip is corrupt.

Delete karaf and install it again.

Also try install other Camel components to see if they work. It may be a problem if your computer uses HTTP proxy to access the internet, then you need to configure this.

`karaf@root()> feature:repo-add camel 2.15.2
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.15.2/xml/features
karaf@root()> feature:install camel-hazelcast
karaf@root()> la | grep -i camel
70 | Active   |  50 | 2.15.2          | camel-core
71 | Active   |  50 | 2.15.2          | camel-catalog
72 | Active   |  50 | 2.15.2          | camel-commands-core
73 | Active   |  50 | 2.15.2          | camel-karaf-commands
80 | Active   |  50 | 2.15.2          | camel-hazelcast`